# book for studying various interpolation

Tags: book-recommendation

Please recommend me a good book to study interpolation techniques such as polynomial interpolation, cubic, spline interpolations, if possible tell me the branch of mathematics that deals with this subject. I want to go in depth with this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topics mentioned above are usually dealt under numerical analysis. Some of the textbooks are:

1. S.D.Conte and C.deBoor, *Elementary Numerical Analysis-an algorithmic approach*,
   3rd Edn., McGraw Hill, 1980.
2. K. E. Atkinson, *An Introduction to Numerical Analysis*, 2nd Edn., John
   Wiley, 1989.
3. C.deBoor, *A practical guide to splines*.

Answer (score 1):

Numerical Recipes is a highly recommended classic. I personally know working physicists who use it whenever they need some numerical work done:

http://numerical.recipes/oldverswitcher.html